# In Azure distributed transaction what is best approach of rolling back full operation if one http call fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api, transactionscope

I have an Azure api app(AzureApi1), which has an action where multiple http requests are made. The operation inserts data to multiple tables to an Azure Sql Db.

It then makes an external api call (ExApi) from within same code. Using the results from the external call it inserts/updates some other tables. This is not in Azure.

Then it calls to another api (AzureApi2) which is in the same resource group as the first one and that inserts data to another Azure Sql Db which is also in the same resource group.

I have used TransactionScope in both AzureApi1 and AzureApi2 which works fine for them individually. However as there is one External api in between and which is not in my control, in case of any failure happened to that api call, I need to rollback the full operation. Currently the first api is rolling back correctly, however, since the second api call is a different http call, it does not fall withing the transaction scope of the first one.
I need an approach to roll back data from the second Sql Db as well if any fail occurs.

What is the best option for manually rolling back in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

For distributed transaction between multi Azure SQL DBs, you could use [elastic database transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview). But elastic database transactions cannot stretch across on premises SQL Server and Azure SQL Databases. You need to create your own Distributed Transaction Coordinator for this situation.

I suggest you create a new Web API which works as coordinator to monitor the status of all the operations. The steps could be like following,

1. If an operation is down, it should send a message(success or fail) to coordinator.
2. If all the operations are completed, the coordinator will send message(commit or rollback) to all the operations. The message depends on all the messages which received from each operation.
3. Every operation will commit the changes and send the commit result (success or fail) to coordinator.
4. The coordinator will send the final state to each operation depends on the commit result received from each operation.
5. We could add timeout for these communicates. If timeout is happen, we need to rollback all the operation.

Comment: Hi @amor thanks for your reply. The solution is nice but somewhat too expensive in terms of time and resource that will be taken. In particular this case where one http request input is dependent on the result from the other http response I am not sure if this solution can be applicable.

Comment: This solution will work for any general distributed transaction. Distributed transaction need a coordinator to monitor the states. The reason we use the distributed transaction is that we want to ensure the consistency for each branch of our application.